# WANTED : All operative systems OS which run on the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: operating-system, raspberry-pi

I bought one of those 512MB Ram supported models, I downloaded a common image with 7 different modes to boot the system and installed the most common one.
I wondered whats possible to manage on this  ARMv6 Chip. Sincu Ubuntu needs  ARMv7 it will not run under this. But is there a list of many or even all ? operating systems or similiar workplatforms which are supported by this super small super computer?
I start here :

- RiscOS
- DEBIAN
- Pidora
- Raspbian
- OpenELEC
- Archlinux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a list that seems to be maintained on the [RPi Distributions page](http://elinux.org/RPi_Distributions) on the eLinux wiki.